# basic vs. derived rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been told that in (propositional?) logic there are so-called "basic rules" and so-called "derived rules". For instance, modus ponens would be a basic rule and modus tollens would be a derived rule. Is there something substantial about this distinction or is this merely a convention? In other words: could modus tollens be regarded as a basic rule and modus ponens as a derived rule? If yes, under which conditions?

Comment: Yes, you can arrange it however you like; modus tollens and modus ponens can derive each other (with suitable additional rules).

Comment: Is this true for propositional logic only or in general?

Comment: *Modus ponens* ($\phi, \phi\to\psi \therefore\psi$) is reguarded as more basic that *modus tollens* ($\lnot\psi, \phi\to\psi~\therefore\lnot\phi$) because it contains fewer logical connectives (the negations) in its statements.